# Gradle task does not take sourceSet configuration

Tags: java, configuration, gradle

There is snippet from [template](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/templates/hello-world/build.gradle)

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
task initSourceFolders { // add << before { to prevent executing during configuration phase
   sourceSets*.java.srcDirs*.each { it.mkdirs() }
   sourceSets*.resources.srcDirs*.each { it.mkdirs() }
}
```

Problem: folders are created as `src/main/java`, not as just `src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is adding additional source directories, rather than overriding the defaults. To do the latter, use:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, see `SourceSet` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).